# HTML5 Canvas Text not appearing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I realize this is a frequently asked question, but I am very confused on why
My code isn't working.
Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dbredred/0ttcefqk/22/) to my fiddle where I have the problem.
The main problem is found on lines 85-87 where it doesn't display.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "White";
ctx.font = '80pt Helvetica';
ctx.fillText("Hello World!",100, 100);
```

Comment: You are drawing stuff in two different functions. The text you write is overwritten by draw();. Put the if-statement that's drawing the white text in your draw-function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're doing update, then render. Render clears the canvas, so the text is also cleared.

Just change the order a little, for example: **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/0ttcefqk/24/)**

```
function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (gameState) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "White";
        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
        ctx.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
    }
    if (gameState === false) {      // draw text for example here instead
      ctx.fillStyle = "White";
      ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("PONG", 100, 100);
    }
    //end of gameState
}

function game() {
    update();
    render();
}
//...
function render() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   draw();
}
```

Pro-Tip: Also look into doing step-debugging. That is often useful with situations like this.